# How to get setInitialRoute to start my Flutter iOS app on different views?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-add-to-app

In flutter I have this:

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/Cards': (BuildContext context) => new PageSelectorDemo(),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) => new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) => new PageSelectorDemo(),
      ),
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter View'),
    );
  }
}
```

In my iOS code I have this:

```
func getFlutterController() -> UIViewController?
{
    self.flutterController = FlutterViewController(project: nil, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    if let controller = self.flutterController
    {
        controller.setInitialRoute("/Cards") // setting the route
        self.messageChannel = FlutterBasicMessageChannel.init(name: "channel", binaryMessenger: controller, codec: FlutterStandardMessageCodec.sharedInstance())
        if let channel = self.messageChannel
        {
            channel.setMessageHandler() { (message:Any?, reply:FlutterReply) in
                ViewController.counter += 1
                self.labelMessage.text = "message recieved: \(ViewController.counter)"
            }
        }
    }
    return self.flutterController
}
```

Why doesn't this work?  The flutter code just loads the initial view and not my view from the "/Cards" route.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been having issues with setting the initial route from iOS and it looks like it may be a bug in flutter:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27216

Answer (score 0):

I found problem is `self.flutterEngine?.run(withEntrypoint: nil)` in document [Add Flutter to existing apps](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps). If you do like that, `FlutterEngine` will run before you create `FlutterViewController` so you cannot `setInitialRoute`.
To solve, you must remove that line in `AppDelegate`, init `FlutterViewController` without `FlutterEngine` `let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`, and `setInitialRoute`, final call `flutterEngine?.run(withEntrypoint: nil)`.